# Box on pgfplot with X-axis at origin?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am doing a plot where I want the X-axis positioned at the origin, which is accomplished with the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dotted,gray}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        clip=false,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=20,
        axis x line = middle,
        grid=both]
            \addplot [domain=0:20,samples=200,red]{sin(deg(x))}; 
            \legend{$\sin(x)$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in the plot seen below:

[image]

Now, as you can see, there are no horizontal borders at the top and bottom of the plot, which for other plots seem to be the default behaviour for pgfplots. I wonder if there is any way to get the horizontal borders (with or without tick marks ...) back for a plot which has an X-axis aligned with the origin?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. As Thorsten has already commented, besides that you can also upvote my answer, if you think it helped you by hitting the uparrow above the checkmark for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw some additional lines at the beginning or at the end of the axis. For details have a look at the code.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
    \tikzset{>=latex}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.13,
        grid style={
            dotted,
            gray,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=20,
        axis x line=middle,
        grid=both,
        % add lines at the bottom and top of the axis as for `axis lines=box'
        % depending if `axis on top' is used, draw them at the beginning or
        % at the end
        execute at begin axis={
%        execute at end axis={
            \draw (rel axis cs:0,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,0)
                  (rel axis cs:0,1) -- (rel axis cs:1,1);
        },
    ]
        \addplot [domain=0:20,samples=200,red] {sin(deg(x))};
        \legend{$\sin(x)$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Just for the record: Besides accepting the answer you could also [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the answer by clicking on the up-arrow above the number on the left side of the answer.